# AngularJS: table edit data + update server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have managed to create a table using AngularJS. In this table I show products from my datbase which can be filtered on category or some other keywords. Now the user should be able to alter this data in this table to update the data in the database.

**AngularJS**

```
categorieFilter = angular.module("categorieFilter", [])
categorieFilter.controller("catFilter", ["$scope", "store", function($scope, store){
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.products = [];
    $scope.categories = [];

    store.getCategories().then(function(data){
        $scope.categories = data;
    })
    store.getProducts().then(function(data){
        $scope.products = data;
    })    

    $scope.filterProductsByCats = function(category){
    $scope.search = category;
    };
}])

categorieFilter.factory('store', function($http, $q){
    function _getCategory (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('api/categories').success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function _getProducts (){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var prods = [];
        $http.get('api/products').success(function (data) {
            for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                prods[i] = {name: data[i][0], category: data[i][2], price: data[i][1]};
            }
            deferred.resolve(prods);
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
        return {
         getCategories: _getCategory,
         getProducts : _getProducts
        };
});
```

**HTML table**

```
<div ng-app="categorieFilter" ng-cloak="" ng-controller="catFilter">
<div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control input-sm pull-right" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search"/>
<div class="input-group-btn">
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
 </button>
</div>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:10px; width:30%;" ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-click="filterProductsByCats(cat.categoryName)" value="{{cat.categoryName}}">
</div>
<table class="table table-hover">
 <tr style="background-color:#ddd;">
  <th colspan="4" style="text-align:left; font-size:16px;"> Category </th>
  <th colspan="4" style="text-align:left; font-size:16px;"> Product </th>
  <th colspan="4" style="text-align:left; font-size:16px;"> Price </th>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy: 'category'">
  <td colspan="4">{{product.category}}</td> 
  <td colspan="4">{{product.name}}</td>
  <td colspan="4">{{product.price}}</td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

Any ideas or reccomendations to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A library I like to use to achieve the editing of data, is angular xeditable. http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

Then save it by posting it back to the webapi